# Android contact update not working

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to update android contact by contact id.

So, I have :
  Herre I supply Contact **id =ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID**
         and string **phone number**

```
     private void updateContact(String id, String phone) {

       ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

       String where = ContactsContract.Data._ID + " = ? AND " + 
             ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
             String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE)
                                                              + " = ? ";

      String[] params = new String[] {id,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
              String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone
                                                             .TYPE_HOME)};

       //  Cursor phoneCur = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,                                            null, where, params, null);
         Cursor phoneCur=  getContentResolver().
                           query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                           null, where, params, null);               
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = 
                                  new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

         if ( (null == phoneCur)  ) {
          createContact(id, phone);
           } else {
          ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate
                 (ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                  .withSelection(where, params)
                 .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, 
                            "somebody@android.com")
                 .build());
                }

                phoneCur.close();

                try {
                    cr.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```

But contact is not updating..what is wrong in this code??

Comment: Go Here => https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/ContactManager

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but your code looks quite messy and I see several mistakes (like you're checking `phoneCur` for `null`, but not if `phoneCur.getCount() == 0`).

Also, why is your code trying to replace the Phone number with an email address?

Anyway, your `where` clause is wrong. If you want to filter by the ID of the RawContact you should not use `ContactsContract.Data._ID`, that's the row ID of the data item.

To search for a specific `RAW_CONTACT_ID`, the `where` clause should look like this:

```
String where = ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + 
    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " +
    String.valueOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE) + " = ? ";
```

#### Update:

The `ContentProviderOperation` to insert a new email address can be created like this:

```
ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.MIMETYPE, 
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, 
        "somebody@android.com")
    .build());
```

Comment: I want to add email id with contact id...Can u please correct me where I am doing wrong? still it is not working

Comment: I've updated my answer. Other than that I suggest you launch the debugger and step through your code to see what actually happens.
At present it's hard to tell what the intention of your code is.